# Como enviar un formulario por Ajax a un método de un objeto

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Saludos comunidad, estoy haciendo unas pruebas con Ajax y POO. Resulta que quiero mandar un formulario a través de Ajax hacia un método que esta dentro de una clase.

La idea es esta:

//Antes de mi formulario tengo esto

```
<?php
  include_once ('class/funciones.php');
  $obj = new Main();

  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  $obj->addAdmin($_POST['name'],$_POST['ape'],$_POST['ced'],$_POST['username'],
             $_POST['pass'],$_POST['estado'],$_POST['id_perfil']);
  }
  ?>
```

1-Mi formulario

```
<form action="" method="POST" class="sign-box">

    <center><div id="resultado" style="display: none"></div></center>

    <input name="name" id="nombre" type="text" placeholder="Tu Nombre"/>

    <input name="ape" id="ape" type="text" placeholder="Tu Apellido"/>

     <input name="ced" id="ced" type="text"  placeholder="Tu Cedula"/>

     <select name="estado" id="estado" >
        <?php 
          $obj->listaEstados();
        ?>  
     </select>

     <input type="hidden" id="" name="id_perfil" value="11"> 
     <input name="username" id="user" type="text" placeholder="Tu nombre de usuario"/>
     <input name="pass" id="pass" type="password" placeholder="Tu contraseña"/>
     <input name="submit" id="enviar" type="submit" value="Registrarme">
</form>
```

Este es mi ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#enviar").click(function(){

    var nombre = $("#nombre").val();
    var ape = $("#ape").val();
    var ced = $("#ced").val();
    var user = $("#user").val();
    var pass = $("#pass").val();
    var estado = $("#estado").val();
    var id_perfil = $("#id_perfil").val();

    $.post("funciones.php", 
        {name:nombre, ape:ape, ced:ced, username:user, 
        pass:pass, estado:estado, id_perfil:id_perfil},

        function(datos){
            $("#resultado").html(datos);
        });
    });
});
```

Y por ultimo esta es mi clase:

```
<?php 

include_once ('conexion.php');

class Main extends Model {

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct(); 
    }

    public function addAdmin($nombre, $ape, $ced, $user, $pass, $estado, $id_perfil){

        $valida = $this->db->query("SELECT admin_usuario FROM tkd_admin WHERE admin_usuario = '$user'");
        $row = $valida->fetch_assoc();

        if($user == $row['admin_usuario']){

            echo 'El nombre de usuario ya existe';
            exit();

        }else{
            $sql = $this->db->query("INSERT INTO tkd_admin(admin_nombre,admin_apellido,admin_cedula,admin_usuario,admin_clave,admin_registro,id_estado,tkd_idperfil)
            VALUES('$nombre','$ape','$ced','$user','$pass',NOW(), '$estado', $id_perfil)");

            if($sql){
                echo 'Te has registrado';
            }else{
                echo mysqli_error();
            }
        }
    }
  }
```

Esto es lo que tengo, lo que no he conseguido como hacer es como enviar ese Ajax a mi método addAdmin de la clase Main, he buscado la forma pero no he dado con la solución. No tengo practica en Ajax por eso la duda. Y obvien la inyección SQL que pueda tener mi código, eso es solo que estoy practicando.

A quien me pueda aclarar esto muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Te puedo ayudar en base a mi experiencia y lo que utilizo.

Yo utilizo javascript puro para la peticion AJAX de la siguiente manera;

```
//Tomando en cuenta que ya estos datos los recogiste con javascript

var usuario = document.getElementById('usuario');
var fecha = document.getElementById('fecha');


function(){ 

        var resultado = document.getElementById("donde_veras_respuesta_servidor");  
        var xmlhttp;

        if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }else{
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){                
                if(xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200){
                    resultado.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            }
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "php/ajax/insertar_registro.php", true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlhttp.send('usuario=' + usuario + 
                    '&fecha=' + fecha);
        }
```

Te explico;

En el metodo Send;

```
xmlhttp.send('usuario=' + usuario + 
            '&fecha=' + fecha);
```

debes incluir las variables tipo array, 'variable=' + valor + '&variable=' + valor...

El ampersand es indispensable cuando vas a enviar mas de 1 variable.

Si quieres enviar archivos mediante ajax esta linea es la indicada;

```
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

ya dentro de tu archivo archivo php recoges los datos con el metodo post como si de un submit cualquiera se tratase.